# Getting Uri of a saved image file

Tags: java, android

When I pick an image from gallery, I can get the Uri for that image as given below:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = result.getData();
        beginCrop(uri);
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, result);
    }
}
```

The format of the Uri retrieved above is **content://media/external/images/media/7266**

However, I am unable to retrieve a Uri in this format when I try to fetch the Uri of an image I just saved as a file:

```
Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            Bitmap bitmap = drawView.getResultBitmap();
            File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "DCIM/Camera/" + s.toString() + ".png");
            boolean success = false;

            // Encode the file as a PNG image.
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                success = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (success) {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{
                                image.getAbsolutePath()},
                        null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {


                            }
                        });

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(image.getAbsolutePath());
                beginCrop(uri);
```

The Uri obtained from above code is **/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/02-04-16 12-49-16.png**

I believe, this is not the correct Uri format, instead just absolute file path. Is there a way out by which I can get the Uri in the format **content://media/external/images/media/** ?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe, this is not the correct Uri format, instead just absolute file path.

You are correct. Use `Uri.fromFile()` to convert a `File` into a `Uri` pointing to the file.

> Is there a way out by which I can get the Uri in the format content://media/external/images/media/ ?

Not readily. At best, in `onScanCompleted()`, you might be able to run some query to get the `Uri` that the `MediaStore` uses. But, until then, `MediaStore` does not know about the file.

The `Uri` that you get from `Uri.fromFile()` is a valid `Uri`, but it will have a `file` scheme, not a `content` scheme.

Answer (score -1):

you can get uri from Bitmap like this :

```
Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      String path = "";
      try {

          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
          path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.